# Create a zabbix alert for a numeric value in a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I am a newbie in zabbix,

I created a script in linux and it will create a file that has a value on it. The data in a file has only one value / number .

For example.

/home/testuser/textfile.txt

If you cat the textfle.txt the output is 50

the data in textfile.txt is 50.

Then I want to create a zabbix alert if the data in that text file will be greater than 100 , zabbix will give me alert.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

as a newbie to zabbix - please know that any alert in zabbix is based on an item value + function so 1st step is to create an item:

[image: zabbix item]

Please make sure user `zabbix` is able to read such file.
After Item creation you can proceed with Trigger creation:
[image]

for future reference I advise you to check and read zabbix ofic. docs. here: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/en/manual/config/items/item

Try to give it a try - it's quite good (IMHO) :) .

Yep and don't forget to have some fun while playing with zabbix :)